# Why does calling an webapi method throw error i.e. Invalid path?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, controller, odata

I have written an odata v3 web api and calling it but it throws error.

**The OData path is invalid.
Invalid action detected. 'Get' is not an action that can bind to 'Collection([EPICOR.Models.TasksList Nullable=False])'.
Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.ParseAtEntityCollection(IEdmModel model, ODataPathSegment previous, IEdmType previousEdmType, String segment) at System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.ParseAtCollection(IEdmModel model, ODataPathSegment previous, IEdmType previousEdmType, String segment) at System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.ParseNextSegment(IEdmModel model, ODataPathSegment previous, IEdmType previousEdmType, String segment) at System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel model, String odataPath) at System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)**

My code:

```
 public class TasksPlanController : ODataController
    {
        private static ODataValidationSettings _validationSettings = new ODataValidationSettings();

        // GET: odata/TasksPlan
        [EnableQuery]
        public List<Models.TasksList> Get(string module)
        {
            //var query= "";

            using (var context = new TasksPlanEntities())
            {
                List<Models.TasksList> ts = new List<Models.TasksList>();

                if (module.ToLower() == "PEMS".ToLower())
                {
                    var query = from PIRTL in context.PIRTaskLists
                                select PIRTL;

                    ts = query.Select(x => new Models.TasksList { PIRCode = x.PIRCode, FunctionalLocation = x.FunctionalLocation, TaskName = x.TaskName, OperationCode = x.OperationCode, OperationNo = x.OperationNo, StartDate = x.StartDate, LastInspDate = x.LastInspDate, NextInspDate = x.NextInspDate }).ToList<Models.TasksList>();
                }
    
                return ts;
            }
        }
```

webapiconfig.cs

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //    name: "DefaultApi",
            //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            //);

            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<TasksList>("TasksPlan");
            config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

            //var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            //config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
        }
```

And also is that valid to call an odata based web api method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the default [routing conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/built-in-routing-conventions) unless you have customized them. In which case the `Get` method should likely return an `IQueryable<TasksList>` as queried directly from your `DbSet`.

I can see that you have some customized logic going on that determines if your return list is actually populated from the database in which case I suggest that you implement this logic as a custom OData Function ([example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions#example-adding-a-function)) where you can define custom parameters that define the logic of your query.

As an alternative approach that may work, you can try using your current code but change the parameter to `[FromQuery] string module` to indicate that the parameter isn't part of the OData route. It is also preferable to return an `IQueryable<TasksList>` directly instead of a new List object as the queryable is passed forward to the `EnableQuery` attribute filter.

Something like this:

```
// GET: odata/TasksPlan?module=PEMS
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Models.TasksList> Get([FromQuery] string module)
{
    using (var context = new TasksPlanEntities())
    {
        if (module.ToLower() == "PEMS".ToLower())
        {
            var query = from PIRTL in context.PIRTaskLists
                        select PIRTL;

            return query.Select(x => new Models.TasksList { PIRCode = x.PIRCode, FunctionalLocation = x.FunctionalLocation, TaskName = x.TaskName, OperationCode = x.OperationCode, OperationNo = x.OperationNo, StartDate = x.StartDate, LastInspDate = x.LastInspDate, NextInspDate = x.NextInspDate });
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<Models.TasksList>().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```